# Will Child processes run and exit in the order they were created

Tags: c, fork, wait

If you were to create children processes that all have the same parent will they run and exit in the order they were created ? For example if you created PID 1 and PID 2 is it possible for PID 2 to finish and exit before PID 1?

Comment: Well, a thought experiment - do you always need to close program windows in the same order that you started them? Yes, they all are child processes to some parent...

Comment: As written this is probably too broad of a question, since any answer will require some pretty big assumptions. If you could add some example code to better illustrate a specific context in which to consider this question, I think you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: in general the answer is - no (can start and finish in any order)  and yes (it is possible).

Answer (score 2):

In general each process can exit as it likes. Nothing on most systems forces them to wait for "siblings" created earlier to exit first.

Some very simple test will show if this is true on the system you use.